# calculate the change by given array of currency

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is what I need to solve I have the price of any product for example 5 coin, ind I need to give the change to a customer for example 5 coin and I have possible array of currency that I can use to give the change [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50,100] here is my code

```js
const currency = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100];
const getChange = (amountInCents) => {
  return currency.reverse().map(coin => {
    let amountCoin = Math.floor(amountInCents/coin);
    amountInCents -= amountCoin * coin;
    return amountCoin
  }).reverse()
};

console.log(getChange(5));
// returns [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Run code snippetExpand snippet
it returns array of [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] where in it by index selected currency needed to give the change to a customer but I need result like [1,1,1,1,1] = 5, [2,2,1] = 5, [1,1,1,2] = 5, any possible variant to give the change I know that this should be done recursively but have no idea how to implement it to code

Comment: Are you looking to just get the number of coins of all types? Or the types of coin that will be given back?

Comment: get the number of coins of all types that possible

Comment: Your requested result has not too much to do with the requirement described

Comment: Checkout https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/ for the algorithm for this.

Comment: this looks good for what I want https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/, but there code returns one number of possible ways, would be great it it returns not a number of ways but like this, lets it will be 5,  returns array like [11111, 221, 1112, 5]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a famous problem. I guess there are many solutions. My solution is recursive. (it isn't necessarily efficient, lots of time, it isn't)

```js
const currency = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100];

const _getChange = (amountInCents, currency, result) => {
  if ( amountInCents < 0 || currency.length == 0) {
    return []
  } else if (amountInCents == 0) {
    return result
  } else {
    newArr = result.map(e => [...e, currency[0]])
    return _getChange(amountInCents - currency[0], currency, newArr).concat(_getChange(amountInCents, currency.slice(1), result))
  }  
};

const getChange = (amountInCents, currency) => {
  return _getChange(amountInCents, currency, [[]])
}

console.log(getChange(5, currency))
```

Comment: Thank you very mach, this is what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reduce` method to add up all numbers in the Array.

This will give you the amount of coins.

```
 result.reduce((allCoins, numberOfDenomination) => allCoins += numberOfDenomination);
```

```js
const currency = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100];
const getChange = (amountInCents) => {
  return currency.reverse().map(coin => {
    let amountCoin = Math.floor(amountInCents/coin);
    amountInCents -= amountCoin * coin;
    return amountCoin
  }).reverse()
};

console.log(
getChange(5).reduce((coins, n) => coins += n)
);
```